# How does a tachometer measure RPM of a motor off of one wire from the unrectified signal of the stator?

Tags: hall-effect

[image: Wiring Diagram of Motor]

In the image, there is a single gray wire coming off of the unrectified side of the rectifier.  That gray wire runs into the wiring harness, up to the dash of the captains chair, and into a 12V tachometer.  I've been told that it is measuring AC cycles in order to extrapolate engine speed but I'm unsure of the method by which you use to measure cycles with only one wire?

Voltage is, by definition, the potential between two different points within a circuit, so how does this work?  Is it using the Hall effect?

Comment: Obviously, the second "wire" is the car carcass, which is used as ground. Can't you see ground symbols all around?

Comment: Well it became obvious once I looked at the innards of wave rectification.  For some reason I had it in my mind that they were isolated.  Not everything is obvious to everyone, Dmitry.  We're not all electrical engineers from birth, like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two wires carrying the tachometer signal - one is the gray wire you see, and the other is the DC Ground buss.  The tachometer measures the potential difference between the gray wire and DC Ground.  It actually "counts" pulses on the gray wire, and, for an anlog tach, converts the pulse rate to a voltage or current to drive the tach meter.

The DC Ground buss is indicated by the inverted triangles at various points in the drawing - like the battery negative terminal.

Comment: Ok, this is starting to clear up for me.  After I reeducated myself on wave rectification I can see that the stator and the battery must share a ground.  I guess the tach doesn't pull off the rectified side because it is smoothed out with capacitors or?

Comment: Yes - the main output of the alternator is effectively filtered to near-DC by the battery, so the tachometer requires a separate output from the alternator.

Comment: By the battery?  Do you mean the rectifier?

Comment: No - the rectifier by itself would produce pulsating DC - half-cycles of the AC produced by the alternator.  The battery prevents the voltage from falling to zero between pulses from the alternator.